# disable / enable addeventlistener onclick

Tags: javascript

```
  var cell_onclick = document.querySelectorAll('.Dicon');
    for(var c = 0; c < cell_onclick.length; c++){
      cell_onclick[c].addEventListener('click', function(){
        handler(this.src);
      }, false);
    }

function handler(_src){
console.log(_src);
}
```

i am using this code to add onclick to my classes , but i also need to disable the onclick at some point. is there anyway to just disable them without remove the addeventlistener , if i remove and add back repeatedly seem no need to use for that , is there a way to disable and enable them ?

Comment: when u want to disable it? for example/

Comment: u can use `$(this).prop("disabled",true);`

Comment: you could try using a simple `if-else` block within the event handler itself with which you can enable/disable the functionality

Comment: did u try `cell_onclick[c].disabled = true;` ?

Comment: at a other function ~ the $(this).prop("disabled", true); is not working.

Comment: so as disabled = true;

Comment: Add `if(disabled) return;` as the first line of the handler. Then add `var disabled = false;` in the containing scope. Then whenever you want to turn off the handler functionality just set that variable to true.

Comment: @nnnnnn exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: Are you setting click handlers on images?  Please specify as the correct solution depends on the type of element.  For example, images and anchors do not have a "disabled" attribute like buttons and inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A class based solution

Other solutions suggest setting the disabled attribute. However, it appears that OP wants to prevent click events on images. The image element does not have a disable attribute (see: [w3c reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#attributes-1)).

As an alternative, OP could simply assign a "disabled" class to the image. The click handler then tests for this class and executes when not present (see MDN [element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)). OP might also use the class to gray the image so that users understand that it is disabled.

**See and run the code snippet below to try:**

```js
var clicks = 0;

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.Dicon'), function(img) {

  img.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (!this.classList.contains('disabled')) {
      this.classList.add('disabled');

      // do something on click
      console.log( 'click ' + (clicks++));

    }
  });

});



function reset() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.Dicon'), function(o) {
    o.classList.remove('disabled');
  });
}


function toggle() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.Dicon'), function(o) {
    o.classList.toggle('disabled');
  });
}
```

```css
.Dicon {
  border: 1px red dotted;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.Dicon.disabled {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: gray;
  /* IE 6-9 */
  border: 1px gray solid;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
click on an image below
<img class="Dicon" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fatcow-icons/20130425/FatCow_Icons32x32/network_wireless.png">
<img class="Dicon" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fatcow-icons/20130425/FatCow_Icons32x32/other_phone.png">
<img class="Dicon" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fatcow-icons/20130425/FatCow_Icons32x32/paintcan.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
  var cell_onclick = document.querySelectorAll('.Dicon');
    for(var c = 0; c < cell_onclick.length; c++){
      cell_onclick[c].addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(this.getAttribute('disabled') == 'disabled'){
            this.removeAttribute("disabled")
        }else{
            this.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        handler(this.src);
      }, false);
    }
```

Let me know, if you get any errors.

Comment: how do i enable and disable it ?

Comment: it should disable the onclick object. since setting 'disabled' attribute.

Comment: hmm it still enable it , did i miss something ?

Comment: which element r u trying to disable. the same element which clicked `cell_onclick[c]` ?

Comment: yup ~ the class .Dicon

Comment: it disables but i need time to enable it right here: https://jsfiddle.net/17kuxtmh/